# Is it possible to switch to a specific keyboard layout via `defaults`, *.plist or similar?

Tags: keyboard, applescript, menu-bar, customization, ios

I have figured out a workable shell script using `osascript` (AppleScript) to automatically switch to US keyboard layout when MacVim activates (triggered by Keyboard Maestro), and Swedish layout when it deactivates:

```
osascript > /dev/null 2>&1 <<-RAW
on changeKeyboardLayout(layoutName)
    tell application "System Events" to tell process "SystemUIServer"
        tell (1st menu bar item of menu bar 1 whose description is "text input") to {click, click (menu 1's menu item layoutName)}
    end tell
end changeKeyboardLayout

changeKeyboardLayout("Svensk - Pro")
RAW
exit $?
```

However, AppleScript is truly slow and I also don't prefer to see the text input menu in the statusbar to flash open when switching back and forth.

### Question:

#### Is there an alternative to my AppleScript approach to *instantly* switch layout?

…I envision something like a `defaults` command or altering any .plist file as potential candidates for the job, only I don't know any specifics.

Two things related to the answer(s) I'm seeking:

1. I'm keen to have the change propagate instantly – faster than the sluggish AppleScript execution.
2. I prefer not installing new software daemons to achieve this. (Suggestions are always welcome, though, but 3rd party apps will likely not qualify as the accepted answer.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.HIToolbox.*.plist` has an `AppleSelectedInputSources` key, but modifying it directly doesn't seem to actually change the layout.

Most of the solutions posted at [MacScripter](http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3amacscripter.net+keyboard+layout) just use UI scripting as well.

There's a small Objective-C utility called [changeInput](http://allancraig.net/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=88%3achanging-keyboard-input-command-line-utility&catid=39%3aobjective-c&Itemid=86) though that should change the layout almost instantly.

Comment: Wow. That command really does the trick. Lots of thanks, Lri.

Comment: The command's website is down, and now redirects to ads.

Answer (score 2):

I write a little program on objective-c cover it in an Alfred Workflow, and you can try it: https://github.com/bimawa/alfredWorkFlows/blob/master/DirectlySwitchKeyboard.alfredworkflow
And now compile binary for cli 64 bit: https://github.com/bimawa/alfredWorkFlows/blob/master/Utilites/DirectlySwitchKeyboard/KeyboardSwitcher/bin/KeyboardSwitcher
on enter wait one argument like "com.apple.keylayout.US"
With [BTT](http://www.bttremote.com/#) working faster.